# How to connect and SQL Developer Database and a Apex 5 application

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds, oracle-apex-5

So I have a Oracle database set up on AWS educate. I then created a connection to SQL Developer. However, I am having trouble trying to connect the Apex application to SQL Developer. I have seen a setup before where you were able to select/insert/update/delete from the Apex application that affected the database shown in SQL Developer. After some research it turns out that I was missing Application Express directory in SQL Developer. In the end I am just trying to connect the Apex application to my Oracle database.

Normal SQL Developer looks like with the application express directory:
[image: normal SQL Developer looks like with the application express directory]

My view looks like this:

[image: This is how MY SQL Developer looks]

Output of query showing I do not have application express installed:
[image: Query showing I do not have application express installed]

Answer (score 0):

I don't use nor know AWS.

Anyway, here's how it goes (from my point of view).

- you have an Oracle database
- it either contains Apex installation (such as 11gXE, which comes with Apex 4.x), or you install Apex - it is just another schema in the database (to put it simply)
- in order to be able to create an application,

  - Apex Admin has to create a workspace (a container for your applications),
  - map that workspace to a database schema (such as SCOTT)
  - create a developer which will be working on that workspace
- as Apex developer, you create an application which then works with tables (inserts, deletes, updates, ...) that belong to that Oracle user
- SQL Developer is yet another tool which lets you connect to the (same) database, including schema which is a "base" for your Apex applications (the same SCOTT)

Therefore, in your case:

- there should be Apex installed on the database which is set up on AWS

  - the rest of the Apex Admin, workspace, developer, ... stuff applies
- you should be able to connect to the same database (i.e. the same user) with SQL Developer, in order to view the same tables (data) from within your Apex application and SQL Developer
- if that's not the case, I don't think that you'll be able to do what you're doing

Comment: A couple of queries to see if (and what version) of Apex is installed in your database instance:  
`select * from apex_release;` and 
`select version as APEX_VERSION from sys.dba_registry where comp_id = 'APEX';`

Comment: Version_No = 5.1.4.00.8